# File Not Found Exception apache common

Tags: android, apache, ftp

Currently I figured out how to connect to my FTP with apache common to download things (enter IP not the ftp.xxx adress). But now I can an FileNotFound, eventhough it really is there and has everything set to 777

I already saw that apache is adding the "/" by himself so normally It should work, uploading is no problem. Any ideas? I can open the file if I enter it in my URL bar

Comment: Even without clien.retrievefile I got this error ?! Even If I pull the file on my phone...

Comment: Do you create the output file before trying to retrieve to it?

Comment: Well the file exists on the FTP server, I thought it would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a file in your system, something like:

```
File f = new File("path/to/file");
if (f.exists() == false)
{
   f.createNewFile();
}
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getAbsoluteFile());
client.retrieveFile("Filenametoretrieve", fos);
```